# Continuity of a differential operator

Tags: analysis

Let $V=C^0([a,b], ||\cdot||_\infty)$ and $W=C^1([a,b], ||\cdot||_{C_1})$ with $$||f||_{C_1}=\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \{|f(x)|+|f'(x)|\}$$

I need to show that the operator $$D: W \rightarrow V$$
$$Df=f'$$

is continuous, that is that there exists a constant $C$ such that

$$||Df||_V\leq C||f||_W \ \forall  f \in W$$

However I do not see the existence of that constant, because that would mean

$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \{|f'(x)|\} \leq C \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \{|f(x)|+|f'(x)|\} \ \forall  f \in W$$  I do know that the derivatives are bounded and so are the function values themselves, but that does not help at all, because the supremums can get arbitrary high and so I fail to find a constant for all $f \in W$. Any hints on that problem are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can take $C=1$ in this case, since the supremum of $|f(x)|$ will be a non-negative quantity.

Comment: I do not believe this to be right, since the supremum of $|f(x)|+|f'(x)|$ might be taken over another x.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right. It is so trivial I did not even see it. Thanks