# Exchange of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in terms of continuity of the differential operator

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, soft-question, function-spaces

Under certain conditions, the derivative and the limit of a real function can be exchanged.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{df_n}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$$

Can this be understood as the continuity of the differential operator on some metric space $\frac{d}{dx}:X\to Y$?

Comment: What about $X=C^1([0,1])$ and $Y=C([0,1])$ endowed with the norms $\| f\|_X=\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}+\|f'\|_{L^{\infty}}$ and $\|g\|_{Y}=\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of a differential operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273928/continuity-of-a-differential-operator)